# Hourly data out of 15 mins interval dataset

Tags: python, pandas, subset

I am looking for help in python code.

I have data with 15 mins values for 1 year. I just want to extract the values at hourly interval. No need to apply mean or any function. Just take the data in a subset.

[Here's my data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Eo3MUsKG1PHcth6Cf73MQFU4bt5BADjW/edit#gid=1477101306)

I am trying this code but this results in missing so many values. The final dataset should have 35040/4 = 8760 values.

```
final_TYP_hourly = final_TYP

final_TYP_hourly['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(final_TYP_hourly.index)

final_TYP_hourly['TimeDiff'] = (final_TYP_hourly['DateTime'] - final_TYP_hourly['DateTime'].iloc[0]).dt.total_seconds() / 60

filtered_data = final_TYP_hourly[final_TYP_hourly['TimeDiff'] % 60 == 0]

filtered_data.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
print(filtered_data)
```

Comment: You'd typically use `resample('1h', on='DateTime').first()`

Comment: Or `final_TYP.groupby(final_TYP['DateTime'].dt.floor('1H')).first()` if you have missing dates and don't want to insert them

Comment: The second approach is working best! Thank you!